What's wrong with Windows 98 button styles?
Is there a practical reason button styles keep evolving?
Looking at images of windows 98 buttons, they seem a lot easier to identify as a button, and despite not looking trendy, they seem perfectly functional.
They could use some colors (blue for primary, red for dangerous, etc), but besides that, I can't think of a single reason buttons have changed since then.
But, I'm not a designer, so if anyone has practical UX reasons buttons are better than they used to be I'd be very interested to learn.

Welcome to the site! Your question has no good answer, I fear: Designers from the Windows world will not explain why the buttons changed, and as all products (and their users with them) change over time, I think it's natural to expect change.

I do think it is a suitable question for this site. Despite the fact that the exact reason for the change is indeed difficult to give, it is possible to give a plausible explanation based on facts from the UX working area. See my answer.

The design principle of the Windows 98 buttons is called Skeuomorphism and was a trend in software interface design to overcome a learning curve for relatively new users. It made it easy to recognise an object and know what to do with it.
Skeuomorph design used a lot of so-called signifiers to create affordances. For example, the shadow on the Windows 98 buttons was added to signify depth to create the affordance that it can be "pressed". As more people became familiar with user interfaces, this was no longer as useful and was considered just clutter on the screen. The need for a cleaner design gave birth to flat design, which is what we are used to today.
Searching for the above mentioned terminology will bring up a lot of articles on this topic. A good example is: https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/skeuomorphism-is-dead-long-live-skeuomorphism
